# Can I make numpy.sum return 0 when array is 0 rows?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sum function that, in a simplified version, looks like this: The row arrays used as indicers change dynamically within my program, but this is a heavily reduced version to demonstrate the issue:

This runs perfectly fine if I throw a few integers into the Row1 array, which is obviously intended, but since there are instances where one of the row arrays will be empty in my program, I was thinking about whether I can make numpy execute this task without throwing an error. Let's

```
arr = np.array([1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1])
Row1 = np.array([])
Row2 = np.array([1,2])
Col = np.array([0,2])

Result = np.sum(arr[Row1[:, None], Col]) + np.sum(arr[Row2[:, None], Col]
```

This could obviously be interpreted to return 4 (0 + 4) but numpy will obviously throw an error as I'm trying to indice a 0 dimension array. I could solve this by doing:

```
arr = np.array([1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1])
Row1 = np.array([])
Row2 = np.array([1,2])
Col = np.array([0,2])

sum1 = np.sum(arr[Row1[:, None], Col]) if len(Row1) > 0 else 0
sum2 = np.sum(arr[Row2[:, None], Col]) if len(Row2) > 0 else 0

Result = sum1 + sum2
```

This would work just fine but would require hundreds of extra lines in my code that feel a bit unnecessary, so I was just wondering if anyone has a more efficient way around this issue. Thank you!

Comment: You could add a define a func that wrapped this logic then you could do `Result = mySum(arr, Row1, Col]) + mySum(arr,Row2, Col)` which wouldn't require so many line changes

Comment: Yes! Of course! How didn't I think of that! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define your own `sum` func to wrap this logic, then you wouldn't need to modify so many lines:

```
In [235]:
def mySum(a, row, col):
    if len (row) > 0:
        return np.sum(a[row[:, None], col])
    else:
        return 0

Result = mySum(arr,Row1, Col) + mySum(arr,Row2,Col)
Result

Out[235]: 4
```

The thing here is to think if I need to write the same bit of code a few times, turn it into a func

Answer (score 2):

> "This could obviously be interpreted to return 4 (0 + 4) *but numpy will obviously throw an error as I'm trying to indice a 0 dimension array*. I could solve this by doing:"

Nope, as long as you make sure the empty array has dtype `int` it works just fine.

```
arr = np.array(([1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]))
Row1 = np.array([], dtype=int)
Row2 = np.array([1,2])
Col = np.array([0,2])

Result = np.sum(arr[Row1[:, None], Col]) + np.sum(arr[Row2[:, None], Col])

Result
# 4
```

Comment: Oh! I had no idea! Thank you :)